# Xcode error when ⌘+Q on iOS Simulator (Picture included)

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I'm really not sure what's going on here, nothing like this happened to me before. Anyways I just updated to Yosemite and now about 50% of the time when I quit the iOS simulator it comes back with an error on Xcode. Anyone else getting this?

[image: picture of problem]

Comment: You quit the simulator. Therefore, you terminated your application. In turn, the debugger is letting you know that your application terminated. I get this all the time.

Comment: @SantaClaus Didn't even happen once for me until I updated. Were you getting this non-10.10? It is slightly annoying as I have to click which class I was working on instead of going straight back to it. Also why would this only happen a partial amount of times? I would think it would either happen always or never.

Comment: always happened . wonder why you never saw it

Comment: @Daij-Djan guess I was just really lucky... I'm in the club now I guess. Hopefully Apple will fix it so it always automatically stops the Xcode process when iOS simulator is quit in the future.

Comment: No, Apple won't fix it because it is the normal behaviour. When you close the simulator the app sends this SIGTERM code to Xcode. Have a look at this https://major.io/2010/03/18/sigterm-vs-sigkill/ and you will understand why the app sends this signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you quit the iOS Simulator, two things (related to this question) happen:

1. iOS Simulator notifies Xcode that it is about to quit.
2. Your process is killed.

There is an inherent race here.  I suspect that if Xcode handles #1 first, that is your working case.

However, Xcode may notice the process being killed before it responds to the notification and will thus drop to the debugger due to the process termination.  I thought that Xcode would then notice the notification about the simulator quitting and kill the debug session, but that seems to not be happening for you.  I suggest you file a radar about that at http://bugreport.apple.com